# Java: Cannot find local variable (inside a method)

Tags: java, android

I'm learning Android and Java, and got into a problem.

i have a simple method that revrese the text i input into her:

```
 public String ReverseIt(String strToReverse){
     String reversed = "";
    for (int i = strToReverse.length(); i > 0; i--){
        reversed += strToReverse.charAt(i);
    }
    return reversed;
};
```

I'm calling this method in a Swithc Controls event OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onReverseSwtichToggleChanged = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(!nameEditText.getText().toString().equals("")){
            String nameInReversed = ReverseIt(nameEditText.getText().toString()) ;
            nameTextView.setText(nameInReversed);
        }
        else
            nameTextView.setText("the EditText is empty");

    }
};
```

For some reason, I'm getting an Exception/Error on the reversed variable inside the method ReverseIt.

the error is: 
reversed = Cannot find local variable 'reversed'

What do i do wrong?

Comment: That's a compiler error, not an exception.

Comment: Also, please get out of the habit of putting `;` at the end of methods, and try to follow Java naming conventions. Neither of those are relevant to the question, but will make you a better Java developer.

Comment: thx, im kinda new to java. can you help me understand what im doing worng?

Comment: I strongly suspect you're not compiling the code you think you are. There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted. Which line is causing a problem?

Comment: reversed += strToReverse.charAt(i);

Comment: I can't see the problem but I guess I should point out that your ReverseIt method has a classic out-by-one bug.

Comment: Use compoundbutton.setoncheck....

Comment: @Alastair you are right, but for some resone i didnt get that error. maybee is a bug in Android-Studio? 
 FAST im new to android, i will check it out. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That compiles just fine for me but you need to change your for loop to look like this:

```
for (int i = strToReverse.length()-1; i>=0; i--){
    reversed += strToReverse.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Actually, not necessarily.  The loop you've posted and the code the OP posted will execute the same number of times. Although you are right the index will be all kinds of messed up unless you adjust it accordingly...

Comment: this worked for me, i also needed to do i >= -1   but i still dont understand why i didnt get any outOfIndexExpetion (wierd). thank you very much :)

Comment: @ChrisThompson Right but the code the OP posted gives me an StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @JoshMaggard yeah, if you do it the OP's way you have to subtract one from the index before you use it

Answer (score 3):

Use this instead to reverse a string:

```
str = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

I know it doesn't *directly* answer your question but you ought not to rewrite methods that are provided for free by the java libraries.